# Python - Make S3 images public as they are uploaded?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using this code to upload images to S3 from python but I need them to be public right away instead of changing permissions manually.

```
im2.save(out_im2, 'PNG')
conn = boto.connect_s3(keys)

b = conn.get_bucket('example')
k = b.new_key('example.png')
k.set_contents_from_string(out_im2.getvalue())
```

I already tried this code:

```
b.set_acl('public-read-write')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using ACLs

Try:

```
k.set_acl('public-read')
```

According to [the boto documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html#setting-getting-the-access-control-list-for-buckets-and-keys) this is how you set a canned ACL on an individual item.

Change the acl on the bucket (as you were doing with `b.set_acl`, will only affecting permissions on bucket operations (such as List Objects in a Bucket), not object operations, such as reading an object (which is what you want).  See [Amazon S3 ACL Overview - Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#permissions) for more details on what the different permissions mean when applied to buckets and objects.

### Using Bucket Policies

However, depending on the key structure for your images, you may find it simpler to setup a bucket policy that grants read access to all keys in a given path.  Then you don't have to do anything special with any individual objects.

[Here is a sample policy that grants read-only access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2).

And [this blog post discusses the differences and combinations between IAM Policies, Bucket Policies and ACLs](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc).